# Server error 500 for header location

Tags: php

In my project at one place I use the following line of code but with this code server shows server error 500. and my code is.

```
header("location:../../views/tileesDesign/viewAlbum.php?album='".$_GET['album']."'&com_id='".$_GET['com_id']."'&d_id='".$_GET['d_id']."'");
```

This line generate server error, without this line I have no error. and I think problem with header location query string.

so, help me to how query string should define in header function?

Comment: write exit after header("Location: ......"); or like this `exit(header("Location: ...."))`

Comment: Did u die() or exit() soon after header?

Comment: Check your error.log file for information about 500error

Comment: this is last line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around the querystring parameter values

```
header("location: ../../views/tileesDesign/viewAlbum.php?album=".$_GET['album']."&com_id=".$_GET['com_id']."&d_id=".$_GET['d_id']);
```

Or to make it even easier to read and debug

```
header("location: ../../views/tileesDesign/viewAlbum.php?album={$_GET['album']}&com_id={$_GET['com_id']}&d_id={$_GET['d_id']}");
```

And using this sample code from the command line and faking up a $_GET array containing all the required occurances :-

```
<?php
//header("location: ../../views/tileesDesign/viewAlbum.php?album=".$_GET['album']."&com_id=".$_GET['com_id']."&d_id=".$_GET['d_id']);
$_GET = array('album' => 'aaa', 'com_id'=> 'bbbb', 'd_id'=>'ccc');

echo "location: ../../views/tileesDesign/viewAlbum.php?album=".$_GET['album']."&com_id=".$_GET['com_id']."&d_id=".$_GET['d_id'];
echo PHP_EOL;
echo "location: ../../views/tileesDesign/viewAlbum.php?album={$_GET['album']}&com_id={$_GET['com_id']}&d_id={$_GET['d_id']}";
```

Generates this putput from either of the above options:-

```
location: ../../views/tileesDesign/viewAlbum.php?album=aaa&com_id=bbbb&d_id=ccc

location: ../../views/tileesDesign/viewAlbum.php?album=aaa&com_id=bbbb&d_id=ccc
```

Comment: it's displaying album and com_id but d_id=null or blank i am getting.

Comment: Have you checked that `$_GET['d_id']` actually contains a value?

Comment: Which option are you using?